# SSIS weird behaviour of Truncation error

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an SSIS package to import data from Oracle to SQL Server. 
The source Oracle table is

> EmpID[INTEGER], EmpTitle[VARCHAR2(20)], EmpName(VARCHAR2(50))
>   
> 1001,MR,KING
>   
> 1002,REVEREND, FORD

The destination table

> ENo(INT),ETitle(VARCHAR(4)),EName(varchar(50))

When i created the package it showed the truncation warning as the destination Title field size is only 6.

When i first run the package it threw an error about truncation(size 20 to size 6), then i tried to redirect the error rows to a temp table to analyse the data, but did not finish it and rerun the package, surprisingly it didn't show the truncation error any more and moving data to destination (with first 6 chars of Title).

I definitely am missing something here, i can ignore this problem but i want to know how the truncation in SSIS works, can we direct SSIS to ignore this error or to raise an error.

I looked at numerous links about this topic, but no one mentioned about this weird behaviour. please some one shed more light on this.

many thanks
john

Answer (score 0):

The truncation error is due to incorrect column width at the destination. Please increase the column width exact same or more than the source. It should solve the issue.

Comment: What i'm trying to understand is how to deal with truncation problem in circumstances it is not possible to increase the field size. would be there be an option to tell SSIS to either to truncate or raise an error.

Comment: If the field size in the destination is smaller than the source..It will through the error or you can either raise error or sent it to error table for futher analysis..

Comment: Hi Please tell me how to change the settings so that it throws the error, at the moment it is not throwing the error even though the destination size is smaller.